# Help unsubscribing from Debian mailing lists

Tags: debian, email, gmail

Apologies if this is not the right place to ask.

My email address is "myname@gmail.com", but I subscribed (to several [Debian mailing lists](https://www.debian.org/MailingLists/)) with the email "myname+web@gmail.com" (I'm 99% sure).

I think because of the "+ trick", the system fail to unsubscribe me. I've tried the [unsubscription forms](https://www.debian.org/MailingLists/unsubscribe.en.html) and the [alternative methods](https://www.debian.org/MailingLists/#subunsub) but nothing worked. I didn't find an email contact to write to either. What should I do?

Comment: "(I'm 99% sure)." You don't have any emails from these mailing lists in which you can check?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about UNIX or Linux systems but rather about subscriptions to mailing lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “+ trick” is used by many subscribers to the Debian mailing lists, so it’s unlikely that *that* is what is causing problems for you, at least not on the mailing list side of things.

First, you need to change the “99% sure” to “100% sure”. To do so, look for an email you received from a Debian mailing list; in Gmail, in the drop-down menu, click on “Show original”, and look for “Return-path” — this will contain the email address that the email was sent to, encoded. For example, `bounce-debian-infrastructure-announce=myname=gmail.com@lists.debian.org` for an email sent from the Debian infrastructure announcements list to `myname@gmail.com`.

Once you have that, any of the available methods should allow you to unsubscribe.

If all else fails, [the mailing lists page](https://www.debian.org/MailingLists/#maintenance) explains what to do, and provides a contact email address to write to.

Comment: You were right, I actually had used "+webtrust" instead of "+web", oops. Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't "Delivered To" have the target email address as well? I don't have any Debian mailing list posts to check, but with other services where I use `+foo`, "Delivered to" has that in the address.

Comment: @muru in many cases it will, but it can’t be guaranteed — any forwarding in between the sender and the final destination will alter the “Delivered-To” header (for example, emails to my ...@debian.org address show the real destination in “Delivered-To”). The advantage of the “Return-path” entry is that it shows the address the mailing list knows about, which is what we care about here.